# Stacking frames of a video file horizontally into a single image

Tags: python, python-3.x

I stumbled upon a post on Reddit a few days ago and I thought I make my own! It's a program to extract from a movie file (.mkv, .mp4, etc.) and stack them horizontally next to each other and make one picture of all the frames available in the movie file. how can I make it more pythonic, readable, and sufficient?

Also, [THIS](https://github.com/blackdead263/framez) is the GitHub link, pull requests are welcome.

Also, the default frame rate (the number of frames to extract one from, to stack up in the output image) is 5.

```
from natsort import natsorted
from ffprobe import FFProbe
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import os

# get and format file path
path = input('All modules loaded, press enter to proceed...\nEnter file path to the file(w/ filename, w/out the last backslash):\n')

if not os.path.exists(path):
    print("Path is incorrect, quitting")
    exit(0)
if path[0] == "~":
    os.path.expanduser(path)  # replace ~ with literal home address
meta = FFProbe(path)
# get metadata
video_duration = meta.metadata["Duration"][:-3]
rate = meta.video[0].framerate
height = int(meta.video[0].width)
# one shot per 5 seconds
freq = int(rate) * 5

# info for the process bar
hours = int(video_duration[1]) * 3600
minutes = int(video_duration[3:5]) * 60
seconds = int(video_duration[-2:])
duration_seconds = hours + minutes + seconds
frames = rate * duration_seconds
output_images = frames // freq  # number of extracted images

(directory, video_name) = os.path.split(path)

dst_path = directory + "/images/"
os.system("mkdir " + dst_path)
os.system("mkdir " + dst_path + "resized")
print("Destination folder created.\n")

print("Extracting frames...")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
i = 1  # current captured frame, how many 24's has already been iterated
os.system('clear')
with tqdm(total=frames) as pbar:
    while cap.isOpened():
        frame_id = cap.get(1)  # first frame in the current stream
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret != True:  # if run out of frames, video finished
            break
        if frame_id % freq == 0:  # if frame# is a multiplicand of freq=24
            filename = dst_path + str(i) + ".jpg"
            i += 1
            cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)  # create the image
        pbar.update(1)
print(str(output_images) + " images extracted successfully.")
cap.release()
del pbar

src_path = directory + "/images/"
dst_path = src_path + "resized/"

images = natsorted(os.listdir(src_path))

os.system("clear")
i = 1
max_counter = len(images) - 1  # all images count
with tqdm(total=output_images) as pbar:
    for image in images:
        if i <= max_counter:  # process until all images are done
            read_path = src_path + image
            img = cv2.imread(read_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            w = 2  # convert to 2px
            h = img.shape[1]  # unchanged
            dim = (w, h)
            resized = cv2.resize(img, dim)
            filename = dst_path + str(i) + "_re.jpg"
            cv2.imwrite(filename, resized)  # create the image
            if i == 1:  # do only once
                print(str(img.shape) + " convert to " + str(dim))
            i += 1
            pbar.update(1)
        else:
            print("Finished " + str(len(images) - 1) + " pictures.")

images_list = natsorted(os.listdir(dst_path))

images_list = [Image.open(dst_path + x) for x in images_list]

# we have the height, user input #3
width = len(images_list) * 2  # number of small pictures, each 2px
out = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))  # create an empty image

x_offset = 0
for im in images_list:
    out.paste(im, (x_offset, 0))
    x_offset += im.size[0]

out.save(directory + "/" + video_name[:-4] + ".jpg")
print("Cleaning Up...")
os.system("rm -rf " + src_path)

print("All set, finishing now.")
```

Answer (score 15):

Some suggestions aimed at more general issues rather than specific details in
your lines of code:

- **Computers are not our friends, no need to chat**. Get user input from the command line, not from `input()`. Interactive user
  input is a bad usage model for the default behavior of a script -- with rare
  exceptions. Use interactivity only for special circumstances, and always
  provide a command-line option to bypass that interactivity. In addition,
  `input()` is terrible for development because it requires you (the coder) to go
  into a dialogue with your script **every damn time** you run it. Super
  annoying. One option for handling command-line input is
  [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). See the script
  below for the template that I usually follow in my scripts.
- **But functions are our friends**. Organize your code into functions. Have each function do one thing. Among
  other things, this approach allows you to test each small piece of behavior as
  you write it.
- **Either do or talk**. Do not `print()` inside your functions that do the actual work (aside from some quite rare exceptions). Functions should take arguments, calculate something or do
  something, and return some meaningful data (or `None`). If the larger program
  requires printing ultimately, use the data returned from functions to do that
  printing. But keep computation and printing in separate realms.
- **No magical tokens in the castle**. Keep literal strings and values out of your code. Instead put them in one
  or more containers. In many situations, I usually just use a `Constants` class
  and module-level global (`con`), as shown below. Good practice, but easy and
  low-tech.

The script template:

```
import argparse
import sys

class Constants:

    EXIT_OK = 0
    EXIT_FAIL = 1

    NEWLINE = '\n'
    NAMES = 'names'
    BAR = 'BAR'
    BAR_PROPAGANDA = 'Sucker, should have picked --bar!'

    OPTS_CONFIG = (
        {
            NAMES: 'path',
        },
        {
            NAMES: '-b --bar',
            'action': 'store_true',
        },
    )

con = Constants()

def main(args):
    ap, opts = parse_args(args)
    if opts.bar:
        print(con.BAR, opts)
        exit()
    else:
        print(opts)
        exit(con.EXIT_FAIL, con.BAR_PROPAGANDA)

def parse_args(args):
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    for oc in con.OPTS_CONFIG:
        kws = dict(oc)
        xs = kws.pop(con.NAMES).split()
        ap.add_argument(*xs, **kws)
    opts = ap.parse_args(args)
    return (ap, opts)

def exit(code = None, msg = None):
    code = con.EXIT_OK if code is None else code
    fh = sys.stderr if code else sys.stdout
    if msg:
        nl = con.NEWLINE
        msg = msg if msg.endswith(nl) else msg + nl
        fh.write(msg)
    sys.exit(code)

def your_function_foo(opts):
    pass

def your_function_bar(opts):
    pass

# Etc.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: I always learn something here. Thank you for mentioning argparse. I am currently working on a project that needs this sorely. I was trying to roll my own solution.

Comment: why create an instance of `Constants`, when you can just reference the static members inside without one?

Comment: @lights0123 Laziness and readability: `con` is easier to type, read, and visually scan.

Comment: 'Constans` class is very interesting, never seen that before. I usually just define constants after import like `TOKEN = "asd"`. Is it a bad practice?

Comment: @politicalscientist No, your approach is fine too. I slightly prefer bundling them under `Constants` for ease of importing. In larger projects, you can end up have a lot of constants, and it can become a drag to import each one you need. (And I dislike `import *`, for different reasons.)

Comment: @FMc, it totally makes sense. thank you!